# How to update dictionary keys that represent the number of times a letter appears in the user's input?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, input, set

For example, I am trying to count the amount of times a letter appears in my input.
Also, I'm trying to use the tools I've learned so far.  I haven't learned the .count tools in the course I'm taking so far.

1st I run this code:

```
any_word = input()
char_amount = {}

for i in any_word:
    char_amount[i] = len(i)

print(char_amount)
```

My input is: `hello`

The result is this:  I get every time is below and my if statements fail to update the key for `'l'` to `2`.

```
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1}
```

My if statements fail to update the key for `'l'` to `2`.  I cant figure out the logic to an if statement to add `1` to the `'l'` key because the duplicate is recognized in every key and the result is below.  I assume i need another variable but i can't think up the logic.  Thanks for any help:

```
{'h': 2, 'e': 2, 'l': 2, 'o': 2}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to count the frequency of letters in text excluding whitespace and numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941943/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-letters-in-text-excluding-whitespace-and-numbers)

Comment: Or maybe this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985203/    It only take <2 min. to search... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using the Counter class from the *collections* module:

```
from collections import Counter

value = input('Enter some text: ')

counter = Counter(value)

print(counter)
```

Thus, for an input of 'hello' you'd get:

```
Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})
```

Counter subclasses dict so you can access it just like any other dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Use `char_amount[i] = char_amount.get(i, 0) + 1` - this will try to get key `i` from dict `char_amount`, if not found returns `0`. Then increases the value of this key by `1`

```py
any_word = input()
char_amount = {}

for i in any_word:
    char_amount[i] = char_amount.get(i, 0) + 1

print(char_amount)
```

Prints:

```
hello
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner but for the sake of completeness it's worth mentioning that the Counter class from the *collections* module is the better option

Comment: @Vlad Can you post the answer with `collections.Counter`? It's always good to see alternatives - I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Why is the Counter class from the collections module is the better option?

Answer (score 1):

Without collections Module:

```
word = input()
char_amount = {}

for char in word:
    if char not in char_amount:
        char_amount[char] = 1
    else:
        char_amount[char] += 1

print(char_amount)
```

Using collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(input()))
```

Comment: is the collections counter faster than doing this with if else statements?

Comment: @Chadeau I haven't tested each method. However, they should take similar time, with collections.Counter being much clearer with many other useful builtin methods.

Answer (score 1):

use built in counter

```py
from collections import Counter

my_counter = Counter("hello")
print(my_counter)
```

```
Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})
```